# Pointer Arithmetic with a pointer to a class array

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

I'm having issues with this code for a bag ADT. I'm using a a pointer array made of a separate class that stores a string and an int.

```
ArrayBag::ArrayBag(int length){
  list = new ReceiptArray [length];
  size = length;
  n= 0;
}

int ArrayBag::getCurrentSize(){return n;};

bool ArrayBag::isEmpty() {
  if (!(n==0)){
    return 1;
    cout << "has items"<< endl;
  }
  else{
    cout << "empty" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
}

bool ArrayBag::add(string item){
  if (!(n==size)){

    (*list+n.item) = item;
    (*list+n.itemnum) = n+1;
```

it is the pointer arithmetic lines above that are proving difficult

```
    n++;
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    cout << "bag full" << endl;
    return 0;}
}

bool ArrayBag::remove(string item){
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
```

Here too

```
    if ((*list+k.item) ==  item){
      (*list+k.item) = (*list+n.item);


      n--;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void ArrayBag::clear(){n=0;}

int ArrayBag::getFrequencyOf(string item){
  int frequency = 0;
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
    if(*list+k.item == item){
      ++frequency;}
  }
  return frequency;
}


bool ArrayBag::contains(string item){
  for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
    if(*list+k.item == item){
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The errors

```
  error: request for member ‘item’ in ‘((ArrayBag*)this)->ArrayBag::n’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
 (*list+n.item) = item;
```

I'm confused on why this is happening. I thought you could index the pointer array this way. It happens anywhere where I try to add the current size of the array to properly index the array and access the arrays member variables.
Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:  `(*list+n.item)` where `list` is a pointer to a `ReceiptArray` (you should probably rename the class from `ReceiptArray` to `Receipt` but that's not your issue.)

You have two issues:

1) An order of operation issue. First `*list` is evaluated which returns an object of type `ReceiptArray`. But you need to increment your pointer *before* you dereference it.

2) Next you try to add `n.item` to this object. But `n` is an `int` and doesn't have an `item` member.  Hence the error.

You want: `(*(list+n)).item = item;`

Or: `(list+n)->item = item`

Or simply: `list[n] = item;`